# Protecting against Creative Commons revisions

Tags: creative-commons

I am looking to purchase digital assets for a project.

The assets are loosely described as CC on the page:

> You can use it for commercial purposes and make edits as much as you like. However cannot distribute. Credit isn't required.

I have tried contacting the owner to clarify however have gotten no response.

Two questions came to mind:

1: [Can an artist revoke his Creative Commons Content](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/can-an-artist-revoke-his-creative-commons-cc-content)

- No they can't - Ok, fine

2: How do you then prove that the paragraph on their website said what I quoted above at the time of purchase?

My honest solution would be to:

1. Setup a video camera pointing at my monitor
2. Navigate to google and google "todays date"
3. Navigate and load up the asset website - scroll to paragraph.

As silly as that sounds, I don't see another way.

Is the above solution valid?

Comment: Wouldn't a screen shot be easier?

Comment: How do you prove the screenshot wasn't edited?

Comment: @SheerKahn how do you prove the video wasn’t edited?

Comment: Valid point, I just feel it would be far more difficult to edit a video - but yes I agree. 

How do I effectively timestamp the statement on the website?

Comment: If the veracity of a video or screen shot are contested, there are companies that can carry out digital-forensic examinations to the evidential standard to say if/when/how a file has been manipulated. But the Wayback Machine might be easier (and cheaper).

Comment: Happy to make that an answer @RockApe. https://archive.org/web/ gives a 'save page now' option which is extremely helpful.

Comment: Use an independent 3rd party, like archive.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q: How do you prove that the paragraph on their website said what I quoted above at the time of purchase?**

**A: With something that has a provable and verifiable date stamp.**

Although your video method is a viable solution, a simpler one to achieve the same objective would be to take a screenshot and save it in a way that preserves its metadata in case its veracity is ever questioned or contested in (for example) court.  If required, there are companies that can carry out digital-forensic examinations to the evidential standard to say if/when/how a file has been manipulated - and sometimes by who.

Another option is to use something like the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/)'s Wayback Machine to preserve the relevant web page (although not every site is included for various reasons given in the FAQ so you'll need to check).